# python - form new list from n elements to the right of a reoccurring word

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Given a list of strings:

```
haystack = ['hay','hay','hay','needle','x','y','z','hay','hay','hay','hay','needle','a','b','c']
```

### Question

How would I form a new list of strings that contain, say, only the three adjacent elements (to the right) of *every* 'needle' occurrence within `haystack`?

Comment: Did you try to write code to solve the problem? What do you imagine are the logical steps to solving the problem? What parts can and can't you do yourself?

Comment: I think you're looking for [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-next-n-elements-from-k-value/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find all the indices of `"needle"` and take 3 values right the indices.

```
# Get all indices of "needle"
idx = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(haystack) if val=="needle"]
#idx -> [3, 11]

# Take 3 values right of each index in `idx`.
[val for i in idx for val in haystack[i: i+4]] 
# ['needle', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'needle', 'a', 'b', 'c']

# want it to be a list of list
[haystack[i: i+4] for i in idx] 
# [['needle', 'x', 'y', 'z'], ['needle', 'a', 'b', 'c']]

# Want to exclude the "needle"
[val for i in idx for val in haystack[i+1: i+4]]
# ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of hacky solution, but it works with only one pass through the list.

```
it = iter(haystack)
output = [[next(it), next(it), next(it)] for s in it if s == 'needle']
# [['x', 'y', 'z'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

This is essentially the short-form of the following:

```
it = iter(haystack)
output = []
while True:
    try:
        elem = next(it)
        if elem == 'needle':
            output.append([next(it), next(it), next(it)])
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

note that, in the short form, you'll get a `StopIteration` error if there are fewer than three elements following a `'needle'`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple list comprehension with list slicing seems to work as well:

```
out = [haystack[i+1:i+4] for i, x in enumerate(haystack) if x == 'needle']
```

Output:

```
[['x', 'y', 'z'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly then you want this...

```
for i in [i for i,ele in enumerate(haystack) if ele=="needle"]:
    Out.extend(haystack[i+1:i+4])
print(Out)
```

Output

`['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c']`